# What is the difference between filter and conv in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, convolution

I am trying to calculate the output of a [LTI system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_time-invariant_system). I came across two different Matlab functions that are supposed to be appropriate for the job: [`filter`](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html) and [`conv`](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html). What is the difference between the two of them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`filter` can handle FIR and IIR systems, while `conv` takes two inputs and returns their convolution. So `conv(h,x)` and `filter(h,1,x)` would give the same result. The 1 in filter indicates that the recursive coefficients of the filter are just `[1]`. But if you have an IIR filter, you can't use `conv`. `filter` can also return the filter states, so that it can be used in subsequent calls without incurring filter transients.

See the [conv](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/conv.html) and [filter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/filter.html) documentation for details.

Comment: so as far as i got it from what i read, if it's an IIR system and i use `conv`, i will get the right output only for an amount of samples equals to the length of `h`. Is that correct?

Comment: Consider the filter `H(z) = [1 - 2z^-1 + z^-2]/[1 - z^-1]`. If you set the input to `x = [1 0 0 0]`, you'll get the results `[1 -2 1 0]` with `conv([1,-2,1],x)` and `[1 -1 0 0]` with `filter([1,-2,1],[1,-1],x)`.

Comment: Actually `conv(b,x)` and `filter(b,1,x)` are not **exactly** the same. `filter` will give you an output with same length as `x`, while `conv` will give an output with length of `length(x)+length(b)-1`.

Answer (score 14):

`conv(x,b)` performs the complete convolution. The length of the result is `length(x)+ length(b)-1`.
`filter(b,[1],x)` gives an output of the same length than `x`. It doesn’t flush the delay line of the filter.

Assume `x` is a row vector. Make `x0 = [x zeros(1,length(b)-1)]`; now `filter(b,[1],x0)` is the same as `conv(x,b)`. This is because the additional 0’s are used to flush the delay line.

Which one is more reasonable? It depends of what you need!

Answer (score 0):

A related answer is the situation in Python. As mentioned above, for FIR filters the functions `scipy.signal.lfilter` and `numpy.convolve` do the same operation *up* to boundary effects.

Assume `len(x) > len(h)`. When using `numpy.convolve(h,x,mode='same')` one gets a vector of `len(x)` but padded with zeros symmetrically.
However, when using `scipy.signal.lfilter the zero padding is *not* symmetrical but one-sided!

One can check that

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import lfilter

h = np.array([1, 2, 1])
x = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0])

fx = lfilter(h, 1, x)
cx = np.convolve(h, x, mode='full')[0:len(x)]

print(fx == cx)
```

gives all "True".

The idea is that the mode full pads maximally with zeros on both sides, giving a vector of size `len(x) + len(h) - 1` (see [Numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html)) and what you need to do is trim the redundant elements in the end.

Answer (score 0):

If filter is applied, result would have same dimensions with applied filter. While applying convolution, would decrease the dimensions of input with filter applied.